# Copying Strings n times for a Java Beginner

Tags: java, string, while-loop, copy, concatenation

I'm taking an AP Computer Science course at my school, and wanted to know how to answer this question:

*Write a method named copies that, given as arguments a string s and a nonnegative integer n, returns the string formed from concatenating n copies of s.*

I've tried this, but you can't multiply strings:

```
public String copies (String s, int n) {
   int copyCount;
   copyCount = 0;
      while ( n > 0 ) {
         s = s * n;
         n = n - 1;
    }
    return s;
}
```

I know similar question has been answered before, but I'm looking for a way to do this using only if-statements and while loops. Our class hasn't gotten to anything past that so far, so if anybody knows how to do it like this, it would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: I also need to be able to show "" when I use 0 as n.

Comment: ahem. what have you tried?

Comment: You can answer it by writing code.

Comment: You wouldn't need `if`, `while` will suffice.

Comment: post some of what you tried!

Comment: why don't you have a try using if-statements and see whether it is working or not with you atempts?

Comment: The code I tried is up now

Comment: `+` operator in Java is overloaded to mean concatenation for strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do what you need.

UPDATED to show "" when n = 0

```
public String copies(String s int n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (n > 0) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < n) {
           sb.append(s);
           i++;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: What do you accomplish with your `if`?

Comment: It guards against non negative ints

Comment: Can you explain StringBuilder? I haven't gotten to that either.

Comment: `non-negative` means positive or zero. OP clearly states: "*nonnegative integer n*"

Comment: You can concatenate Strings by doing String s = "a"; s = s + "b", this would return "ab: but it is inefficient. StringBuilder is a more efficient way of concatenating Strings and is part of the standard JDK.

Comment: @WaldoAldoOswaldo See  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html

Comment: I've tried using this code, and I understand StringBuilder now, but I'm also trying to get it to show "" when I enter 0 for n

Comment: Change StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s); to StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

Comment: @lucasweb I have two. 1. You're currently guarding against non-positive, so your reply simply incorrect.  2. There is no need to guard at all as per OP's description of the task.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

```
String copies(String s, int n) {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  for (int count = 0; count < n; ++count)
    builder.append(s);
  return builder.toString();
}
```

I chose to use a `for` instead of a while (for cleanliness), but you should be able to make any mods you need pretty easily :p

Comment: Can you explain StringBuilder? I haven't gotten to that either.

Comment: @WaldoAldoOswaldo That's the preferred way of using a mutable string in java. You can also use a `StringBuffer`, but that's frowned upon by most people. The point is to avoid doing String concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create int n copies of String s you should try something like this

```
// Return a String, containing n copies of s.
public static String copies(String s, int n) {
  // More then 0?
  if (n > 0) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
      sb.append(s);
      i++;
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
  // Just return the input.
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain StringBuilder? I haven't gotten to that either.

Comment: String(s) are immutable in Java. When you use the `+` operator on two strings in java (e.g. `"Hello" + " World"`), the String class uses an internal StringBuilder (or on older Java versions a StringBuffer) to perform the operation. Take a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)